# Gradle sync failed because of "Unable to load Maven meta-data from ...", but I can download the file via browser

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

```
buildscript {

repositories {

    google()

    jcenter()
    jcenter{ url"http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
    maven {
        url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
    }

}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$android_plugin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "com.mob.sdk:MobSDK:+"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}


allprojects {
repositories {

    google()

    jcenter()
    jcenter{ url"http://jcenter.bintray.com"}

    maven {
        url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
    }

}

}
```

Here is my gradle file. When do gradle sync, an error comes out.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.mob.sdk:MobSDK:+.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mob/sdk/MobSDK/maven-metadata.xml.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mob/sdk/MobSDK/maven-metadata.xml'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mob/sdk/MobSDK/maven-metadata.xml'.
```

But I can download the url http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mob/sdk/MobSDK/maven-metadata.xml  directly via browser.
Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      maven {url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'}
    }
 }
  ...............
  ...............
allprojects{
   repositories {
      maven {url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'}
    }
}
```